# Filter for calculated date

Tags: date, dplyr

I have troubles to filter my date for a calculated date

Here's my data:

```
   > dput(df)
    structure(list(date = structure(c(1490652000, 1490738400, 1490824800, 
    1490911200, 1490997600, 1491084000, 1491170400, 1491256800, 1491343200, 
    1491429600, 1491516000, 1491602400, 1491688800, 1491775200, 1491861600, 
    1491948000, 1492034400, 1492120800, 1492207200, 1492293600, 1492380000, 
    1492466400, 1492552800, 1492639200, 1492725600, 1492812000, 1492898400, 
    1492984800, 1493071200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
        date2 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1491256800, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1491775200, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        1492466400, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1493071200), class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = 87:115, class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to filter the date column for all dates that are 7 days before date2, but I always get dataset with 0 observations:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  filter(date == date2 -days(7))
```

However. the following works fine:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  filter(date == date2)
```

I don't understand why!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second filter works and returns only rows where `date == date2`.
The desired filter needs the lubridate function `days` also it needs all rows in `date2` column to have a valid date value.

First `fill` the `date2` column then do the filter

```
df %>% tidyr::fill(date2, .direction = "up") %>% 
  filter(date == (date2 -lubridate::days(7)))
```